# error and warning bar in windows8 metro app

Tags: javascript, windows-8, warnings

As per this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465304.aspx#errors), we need to show error and warning bar when there is a non-critical error that applies to the whole app and your app can suggest a solution.

So i want to know how to show error and warning bar in windows8 Metro apps created using c# or javascript.

Hopes this question is clear...

Comment: I'm sorry my answer is about XAML/C#... I have no idea how to translate this into HTML/Javascript. I'm leaving it here nonetheless, perhaps you will be able to translate it.

Comment: I don't see a link in your post to and image or example?

Comment: @DominicHopton click on the word link it will redirect u ....
it works perfect at my end.... hopes it will wrk at ur end too......

Answer (score 6):

You can display a Warning or Error Bar exactly like the builtin Weather App is doing, by creating the UI for a horizontal stretching Panel that gets displayed via a animated storyboard like so.

**Create the Warning Bar Control**

In the body of your XAML Page, put the following block of code.

```
        <!-- StatusBar for temporary feedback and diagnostics -->
    <Grid x:Name="barStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="#FF383026" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >

        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="barStatusCompositeTransform" TranslateY="-68"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8" />
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinWidth="150" Background="#FF50B7FF"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtStatus" Grid.Row="1" Text="Warning or Error Text Placeholder" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,0,0,0" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="150" Content="{StaticResource btnCloseText}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="btnClose_Click" />
    </Grid>
```

This block of code creates a horizontal canvas, that spans the width of the screen and aligned at the top. You'll notice that, by default, it is placed offscreen (translated by an amount of pixels equal to its height above the screen). It is also "collapsed" to make sure it is not displayed.

In this example, the txtStatus TextBlock can be changed programmatically, in order to provide appropriate feedback to the user, depending on the situation in your application.

**Creating an Animation to Display or Dismiss the Warning Bar**

In order to provide smooth animation when displaying or dismissing the Warning or Error Bar, you'll need to create a StoryBoard. Please, put the following block of code in your page's resources area, at the top of your XAML file.

```
    <!-- Animations and transitions -->
    <Storyboard x:Name="sbStatusBarToVisible">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="barStatusCompositeTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateY" From="-68" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="sbStatusBarToCollapsed">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="barStatusCompositeTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="TranslateY" From="0" To="-68" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
    </Storyboard>
```

There are two animations here. The first one is designed to smoothly change the amount of pixels by which the Warning or Error Bar is translated above the screen, from a negavite amount to zero. This, in effet, makes the bar appear to "slide down" when it gets displayed.

The second animation reverses the animation and is designed to be used when dismissing the Warning Bar.

**Display or Dismiss the Warning Bar in your Code**

In your C# code-behind, here is how you would asynchronously display the Warning or Error Bar as appropriate for your application.

First, an animation helper function:

```
    private void ToggleStatusBarVisibility()
    {
        var targetVisibility = barStatus.Visibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed ? Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible : Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

        barStatus.Visibility = targetVisibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible ? targetVisibility : barStatus.Visibility;

        var animation = "sbStatusBarTo" + targetVisibility.ToString();
        var sb = this.FindName(animation) as Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard;
        if (sb != null)
        {
            sb.Completed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                barStatus.Visibility = targetVisibility == Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed ? targetVisibility : barStatus.Visibility;
            };
            sb.Begin();
        }
    }
```

This function selects one of two animations, whose name begins by "sbStatusBarTo" defined earlier in your page as resources. Then, it starts the StoryBoard animation, that will finish asynchronously.

Here is how to trigger it:

```
    private void DisplayStatus(String message)
    {
        // TODO: protect against multiple invocations
        // while the status bar is displayed...

        txtStatus.Text = message;
        ToggleStatusBarVisibility();
    }
```

When the user wants to dismiss the Warning Bar, he or she clicks on the Close button, whose code is shown here for reference:

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // can only be called when the status bar is visible
        ToggleStatusBarVisibility();
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a JS solution, this is how I would do it.

I believe you are looking for the `AppBar` control.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229670.aspx

You can try to follow this QuickStart Instructions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465309.aspx

Here is some sample code that you can use to create a warning bar

```
<div id="appbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{sticky: 'false', placement: 'top', layout: 'custom'}">
    <div id="errorMessage">Your Error Message</div>
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmd', label:'Command', icon:'placeholder'}" type="button" style="float: right"></button>
</div>
```

The `placement` property maybe useful in the case you want to display the "warning bar" at the top of the screen. You can set the `placement` property to `Top` or `Buttom` to place it at the top of the screen or at the bottom of the screen

Another important property to note is the `layout` property. You have to set it to `custom` so that you can customize your own layout. Otherwise, Visual Studio won't let you put text on the app bar.

Comment: sry.....As per my knowledge both the appbar and errorbar can't be same....
i want like this [image](http://postimage.org/image/s8top1jqb/)

Comment: @SubratNayak I thought the same thing before, until I look at this post http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/6c6ca82b-7586-4667-baba-45753864513b/

Comment: @Subratnayak. Which part of the WarningBar functionality that you think that can't be achieved by the AppBar? If you try this code in a default app generated by Visual Studio, all you ask in the image you attached can be done by some extra css. I can probably add more functionality or css if you want.

Comment: An AppBar is invoked directly by the user (whereas a Warning Bar is not). It may be dismissed automatically (whereas a Warning Bar usually requires explicit dismissal). They really are distinct.

Comment: @MaximeLabelle Thanks for the reply. In terms of usage, I 100% agree that they are different. And they really should have been different UI Controls if MSFT had offer one. The problems that you are talking about can be easily fixed by adding properties to the AppBar control. E.g. You can call `appbarElement.WinControl.show` to show the appbar when needed. You can set the `sticky` property to make sure it doesn't easily go away. Honestly, I am looking forward to an alternative solution too. :)

Comment: What's wrong with my answer below ? It seems simple enough without having to pervert the way an AppBar is designed to work. How would you code an AppBar *and* a Warning Bar on the same page?

Comment: @MaximeLabelle No no. I am not saying your answer is wrong and I think I have never said that your approach is wrong. I actually enter the answer an hour b4 your post.  Your approach is good in C#, I am just providing the way that I would do it in JS.

Comment: @MaximeLabelle Good question for how to have an AppBar and a WarningBar on the same page. I never thought about that until you point out. But you can always modify the property on the AppBar `<div>` and update the commands. Again, your approach is good, this is just how I would do it in JS.